# Same Target Record should auto populate when user clicks on CR of Questionnaire of that record

Tags: archer

I am working in RSA archer & I am making a questionnaire. I have put the Cross reference of questionnaire in Application, I want when user clicks of CR add new the existing record number should populate in Target field already so that user is not supposed to select the record number from popup. How I can achieve that?

I tried to use filter in CR but did not worked

Comment: When you click the Add New link in the application does it take you to the questionnaire layout or does it as you to select a "target" record?