# Configuring Archer questionnaire to Auto Populate the Target/Hierarchy

Tags: archer, rsm

In the past with other questionnaires, we don't have any issues simply cliking "add new record" for a questionnaire, under a given application, and the new record automatically associates with the application record (ie. the key ID). For some reason, when I click "add new record", now I have to pick the hierarchy myself. Does anyone know a good way to change this?

I have tried changing the hierarchy properties, but haven't had any luck there. There don't seem to be any helpful options in the Related Record/Cross-Reference data field properties either, from what I can tell. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you have to select a specific level of said application when creating a questionnaire.  There’s no way to “default” a specific level unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the response here. I can understand that, but I'm confused as some of our applications (and their associated questionnaires, listed within them) automatically populate a hierarchy after clicking "add new"/"create new record". Any idea why? Could be related to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75896660/same-target-record-should-auto-populate-when-user-clicks-on-cr-of-questionnaire

Comment: Do those other applications have multiple levels?  An example of a leveled application would be Policies or Authoritative Source and a "flat" application would be Findings or Control Standards.

Comment: Interestingly, no. The other application is "Business Cycle" and the only cycle is "Business Processes". The problem application, "Control Procedure" with the problem questionnaire also only has one level, "Control Procedures". I am viewing this from the editor/designer page.

Comment: If the Control Procedure is a flat application, then creating a new questionnaire record shouldn't ask which level to create the questionnaire on.  Best to open a support ticket so that they can see what's going on.